# Big Sur desktop stacks: Newly added files replace the stack, instead of being added to it

Tags: finder, big-sur, desktop

When using stacks on your desktop, macOS will place all files added (copied or dropped) to the desktop into its appropriate stack, or create a new one if that is the first file of its kind.

On my personal computer the stacks work as I described, which seems to be the way it was intended. On my work computer, however, the newly added file replaces the whole stack, which becomes unaccessible.

Let's say there is a stack called Images, and all JPGs and PNGs are under it. If I drag a new image to my desktop, the stack "Images" disappears and in its place I now see the image I just dragged with its filename right underneath it. If I single click on the image, I simply select it. If it was a stack, a single click would expand it to show the files in there. If I add more than one image to the desktop, then they each start to occupy their own space just like a regular desktop would.

Restarting Finder or disabling and enabling stacks would fix it. Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this behavior? Thanks!

Laptop with issues is at Big Sur 11.6.1.

Comment: Are they on different macOS versions?

Comment: They are today, yes. I currently cannot upgrade my work laptop to a version that is not approved by our IT Security. But at one point both laptops were at the same version and their behavior was still different.